# JS) for loop for star pattern

Tags: javascript

There is a part that I don't understand in this star pattern answer.

```js
let star3 = "1";

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  for (let k = 3; k >= i; k--) {
    star3 = star3 + "2";
  }
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    star3 = star3 + "* ";
  }
  star3 = star3 + "\n";
}
console.log(star3);
```

In the answer the star3 is declared as a global scope using let and I assumed that it should be accumulated whenever the inside of for loop is processing but had a totally different result than expected.

I understand that 1222* is logged on the first line but don't know why it showed me the 22**

[image]

Comment: after it finishes concatenate `* ` (`star3 = star3 + "* ";`), it concatenates `\n` (`star3 = star3 + "\n";`) which means to break the line and start a new one. that's why you don't `2` after `*`.

Comment: Oh my god, I don't know why I could not see that thing carefully! such a great point. thank you so much!!

Comment: @Layhout why comment and not answer?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen when the answer doesn't involve writing code, i usually answer in the comment. thanks for asking. :)

Answer (score 1):

after it finishes concatenate `*` (`star3 = star3 + "* ";`), it concatenates `\n` (`star3 = star3 + "\n";`) which means to break the line and start a new one. that's why you don't see `2` after `*`.